# Use www.domain.com and domain.com with EC2 and Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, cname, amazon-route53

I have the following Route53 settings:

[image]

My CNAME allows users to type `www.obystudio.com` which is pointed at my Elastic Load Balancer.

Whenever I try to create a second CNAME so users can type `obystudio.com` and it will redirect to `www.obystudio.com`, I get an error saying I can't use `obystudio.com` in the same apex.

Does anyone know a solution to use that will allow users to type either `www.obystudio.com` or `obystudio.com` and have them both work?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`obystudio.com` is a root domain name. You can't use a CNAME record for that, you have to use an A record.

There are instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-domain-names-with-elb.html) for pointing an A record to an Elastic Load Balancer.

Also, don't try pointing one domain to another. Point them both directly to the Elastic Load Balancer.

Comment: This blog post can be helpful in setting up a naked domain redirection: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/root-domain-website-hosting-for-amazon-s3/. And http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html

Comment: @Evgeny he doesn't need any of that if he is using Route53 and an Elastic Load Balancer. He can just setup an A record with an alias to the load balancer.

Comment: Yes, setting up an A record aliased to an ELB is definitely a valid option. My impression was @jape was interested in redirecting users from domain.com to www.domain.com which is what the links above are about.

Comment: Also, this blog post sheds some light on why CNAME-ing a naked domain (domain.com) isn't a good idea: http://joshstrange.com/why-its-a-bad-idea-to-put-a-cname-record-on-your-root-domain/. Short version is - CNAMEd record by definition can't co-exist with any other records named identically (but of different type). For domain.com there are two other records of type SOA and NS created for each Route 53 Hosted Zone (you can actually see them on the screenshot above), thus making it impossible to CNAME a domain.com.

Comment: Ah that's true about the redirect. I was mainly focusing on his error message in Route53.